# Unorderd list for menu float left can't make wrap

Tags: html, css, menu

The application must fit 1024x768

We have a varied length menu - sometimes the menu looks like this...

```
<ul>
   <li><a>link 1</a></li>
   <li><a>link 2</a></li>
   <li><a>link 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

In other users/roles it can have many more like this...

```
<ul>
   <li><span>link 1</span></li>
   <li><span>link 2</span></li>
   <li><span>link 3</span></li>
   <li><span>link 4</span></li>
   <li><span>link 5</span></li>
   <li><span>link 6</span></li>
</ul>
```

and the css looks like:

```
#menu
{
   list-style-type: none;
   min-height: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   background:#E5E5E5;
   padding-left: 35px;
   border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
}
#menu li
{
   min-height:30px;
   border-right:1px solid #CCC;
   border-left:1px solid #FFF;
   padding:0px 10px;
}
#menu li span
{
   display: block;
}
#menu li, #menu li span
{
   float: left;
   height: 30px;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align:center;
}
```

There is a grey background on the ul -> if the width of the items exceeds 1024px the items should wrap to the next line - and they do but the grey background is not there except oddly enough in IE7 - very annoying issue. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you made an example page on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are floating everything in the menu, IE does not properly recognise that content is contained with the `ul`. YOu can fix it easily by adding these rules:

```
#menu {
  overflow: hidden; // ensures container wraps child content
  zoom: 1; // needed to trigger hasLayout in IE6
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an overflow problem. Add `overflow: auto` to your `#menu` style. In IE you will probably have to force hasLayout, you can do this with `zoom: 1`.